# Why does INVOKE facility in the C++11 standard refer to data members?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

$ 20.8.2 of the standard describes the INVOKE facility that is mostly used to describe how callables are called with variadic argument lists throughout the standard library:

> Define INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN) as follows:
>
> — `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when f is a pointer to a member function of a class T and t1 is an object of
>   type T or a reference to an object of type T or a reference to an object of a type derived from T;
>
> — `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when f is a pointer to a member function of a class T and t1 is not one of
>   the types described in the previous item;
>
> — `t1.*f` when N == 1 and f is a pointer to member data of a class T and t1 is an object of type T or a
>   reference to an object of type T or a reference to an object of a type derived from T;
>
> — `(*t1).*f` when N == 1 and f is a pointer to member data of a class T and t1 is not one of the types
>   described in the previous item;
>
> — `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.

What are the third and the fourth item for? As far as I can tell, they don't call `f` even if `f` is callable. What's the user case for them. Maybe it's a typo in the standard and `*f()` was intended?

Comment: How can it be a typo when they specifically talk about "pointer to member data"? Also, the `(t1.*f)(...)` case is dealt with directly above.

Comment: @Xeo: Member data may be a callable object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`INVOKE` is specified like that because you can actually bind member data pointers (through `bind` and `mem_fn`):

`§20.8.10 [func.memfn]`

> `template<class R, class T>`
> *`unspecified`*`mem_fn(R T::* pm);`
>
> p1 *Returns:* A simple call wrapper (20.8.1) `fn` such that the expression `fn(t, a2, ..., aN)` is equivalent to `INVOKE(pm, t, a2, ..., aN)` (20.8.2). `fn` shall have a nested type `result_type` that is a synonym for the return type of `pm` **when `pm` is a pointer to member function**.

I don't think that special wording would exist if you couldn't bind member data pointers.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct X{
  int n = 5;
};

int main(){
  X x;
  auto f = std::mem_fn(&X::n);
  std::cout << f(&x) << "\n";
}
```

Output: 5

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e62e72d203d9da6d918af1e5601384c5)

Comment: @Cubbi: You forgot to fix some wording on the `std::mem_fn` page, fixed that (and also the member typedef errors). :)