# Binding data members not working in VS2012?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

When using std::bind, I was able to bind data members in VS2010 by passing a pointer or an iterator rather than the object itself. However, it no longer seems to work in VS2012:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<string, int>> v; 
    v.push_back(make_pair("abc", 10));
    auto f = bind(&pair<string, int>::second, v.begin());
    int res = f();
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(http://ideone.com/n1KWu)

GCC also compiles & runs this code fine, but VS2012 gives me an error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type' to 'int'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=false,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Funx=std::_Pmd_wrap<int std::pair<std::string,int>::* ,int,std::pair<std::string,int>>,
1>              _Btuple=std::tuple<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::pair<std::string,int>>>>>,
1>              _Ftuple=std::tuple<>
1>          ]
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
```

Note that if I pass an std::pair instance instead of an iterator or a pointer to it, then VS2012 is happy.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::mem_fn` (and `std::bind`) is specified and implemented in terms of the `INVOKE` facility, see `§20.8.10 [func.memfn] p1`

> *Returns:* A simple call wrapper (20.8.1) `fn` such that the expression `fn(t, a2, ..., aN)` is equivalent to `INVOKE(pm, t, a2, ..., aN)` (20.8.2).

As such, it's very likely a bug in MSVC's implementation of `INVOKE`, specifically the fourth requirement:

`§20.8.2 [func.require] p1`

> Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> - `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
> - `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
> - `t1.*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
> - `(*t1).*f` when `N == 1` and f is a pointer to member data of a class `T` **and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item**;
> - `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.

The bold part basically says that when `f` is a member pointer (of any kind) and `t1` is not a reference, try to dereference it and apply the member pointer after that. This should be the case for your code, as an iterator is not a reference to `T`. GCC implements this correctly.

[I advise filing a bug report on MS Connect.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=5303&FeedbackType=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you check a reference [like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) you will see that the first arguments should be

> function object that will be bound to some arguments

In other words, you should not be able to bind data members or variables, only functions and function-like objects.

To quote from the C++11 standard (section 20.8.9):

> The function template bind returns an object that binds a callable object passed as an argument to additional arguments.

Comment: You can perfectly fine bind a data member. `std::_Pmd_wrap`, the "Pmd" is "Pointer to Member Data". See also [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12638715/500104). The problem here is the iterator binding. An iterator doesn't support `(it->*member_ptr)`, while a normal pointer does and a reference supports `(r.*member_ptr)`. It's all defined in terms of the `INVOKE` facility that describes how the whole binding machinery should work.

Comment: My understanding is that data members are included in the definition of a callable object, so it's legal to use them with bind (I've been doing that for years with boost::bind by the way). Also, as I noted in the question, the problem isn't limited to iterators. I can't use a regular pointer either, so I don't think @Xeo's comment clarifies the situation for me. And why does my code work fine with GCC?

Comment: @Alex: It most likely works for GCC because *their* iterators have `operator->*`. And it most likely does *not* work for MSVC thanks to a bug in MSVC's implementation (I encountered that one before).

Comment: @Xeo, if it's a bug in MSVC then I guess it's the answer to my question. Would you like to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?